# Change color of textview based on values from ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: java, android, xml, arraylist, colors

Hi I have the following ArrayList of elements which takes values from an xml file. After that the data is fed to a simple adapter which displays it. I want the color of R.id.stock_mov to change based on the value. If it is negative->red if it is positive then green. I cant find a way on how to do this

```
         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> stackItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ();
    // final HashMap<String, String> dspStack = new HashMap<String, String>();

     NodeList stock = doc.getElementsByTagName("stock");
        for (int i=0; i<stock.getLength(); i++){
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Node nodeCurr = stock.item(i);
             Element currElmnt = (Element) nodeCurr;
             map.put("name", parser.getValue(currElmnt, "name"));
             map.put("val", parser.getValue(currElmnt, "val"));
             map.put("mov", parser.getValue(currElmnt, "mov"));
             stackItems.add(map);

        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, stackItems,
                R.layout.stocks_def_item,
                new String[] { "name", "val", "mov"}, new int[] {
                        R.id.stock_name,

                        if(stackItems.get(i)>0)
                        R.id.stock_val,
                        R.id.stock_mov,});

        setListAdapter(adapter);


}
```

Comment: That code is not compiling, right?

Comment: Could you please show your stocks_def_item XML layout?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in your `adapter`'s `getView()` method. Have it check the value of the stock and then set its respective color accordingly:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // use the ------- ^position^ parameter to access the current stock's value
    double currentStockValue = ...;

    TextView stockMove = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.stock_mov);

    if( currentStockValue > 0) // if the current stock's value is positive
        stockMove.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#6AC36A")); // set text color to green
    else
        stockMove.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF3300")); // set text color to red   

    ...
    return convertView;
}
```